# Debug remote devices with Chromium

Tags: android, linux, debugging, ionic-framework, chromium

I try to debug my app generated with ionic, but when open the chromium debugger, I have the follow problem...

[image]

### Debugger have a bug ??

My configuration 
Browser version: Version 63.0.3239.108 (Developer Build) (64-bit)
My os: Linux Arch

Please let me know if to anyone have the same problem and how to fix it

cheers

Catcoderphp